# installing pywin32 in python 3.3.3

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32

I don't know if this is a simple question or not. I'm trying to install pywin32 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/

However,I'm running 3.3.3, and when the installation starts, it tells me that version 3.3 is not not found in the registry.

I have googled some workarounds but most are directed towards 2.x versions for similar issues. Any suggestions?

Thanks!!

Comment: ok, well yeah, that was my bad, thanks!!, however, now i get this when I do import win32com.client:

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: 1) c:\windows\system32\   2) returns 2 lines : c:\windows\system32\  and c:\syswow64\ and 3) returns python33\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\

Comment: ok, that returns: <module 'pywintypes' from 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\pywintypes33.dll'>, sorry for my ignorance but would this replace the import win32com.client?

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading a different installer. Make sure it matches the Python you are using. It has to match the Python version (e.g. 2.7, 3.3) and match 32-bit or 64-bit.

Type python at a command prompt

```
python
```

The Python interpreter starts up and tells you about itself.

```
Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:24:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Look at the first line the interpreter prints when it starts up. In this example, it is telling you that it is Python 3.4, 32 bit. So, the file to download for that setup would be [pywin32-219.win32-py3.4.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/pywin32-219.win32-py3.4.exe/download). That will get you version 219 of pywin32, which is the latest version at the time of this writing (July 2014)

From the README

> Some packages have a 32bit and a 64bit version available - you must download
>   the one which corresponds to the Python you have installed.  Even if you have
>   a 64bit computer, if you installed a 32bit version of Python you must install
>   the 32bit version of pywin32.
>
> If the installation process informs you that Python is not found in the 
>   registry, it almost certainly means you have downloaded the wrong version -
>   either for the wrong version of Python, or the wrong "bittedness".